# Ударение в имене Орест

Tags: ударения

Как правильно поставить ударение в имене Орест? Орест или ОрЕст?

Answer (score 1):

Орест - горец (греч.)
В греческом оригинале ударение на втором слоге, такое же ударение рекомендуют словари русских личных имен.  Хотя в русских переводах с древнегреческого встречается ударние на первом (особенно это касается переводов Иллиады, где это имя носит несколько персонажей).

В языке же смещение ударение на первый происходит в западноукраинснких говорах, где имя достаточно популярно. Оттуда  заимстововано европейскими языками и канадо-американским английским, там тоже ставят ударение на О.

Из известных носителей имени - художник Орест Кипренский, ударение в имени на втором слоге.

Comment: Читала о шутке 19 века: "Назовите ребенка Орестом, Оресты нынче в моде". Суть - политическая, на слух получается "арест". Но это возможно, только если ударение на Е.